# TemplateDoesNotExist at, when run at VPS

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

when I use my Django site at my localhost it's gonna good, but unfortunately when I run it at my VPS I have an error TemplateDoesNotExist at, but all files exist
I use Django 11, Python3

[image]

My settings file looks like:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   '**********'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'joins',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'lwc.middleware.FooMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lwc.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + "\Templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lwc.wsgi.application'
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

my urls in lwc is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from joins import views as joinsView
from lwc import views as lwcView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', joinsView.home, name='home'),
]
```

my view in Join APP is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from .forms import EmailForm, JoinForm
from .models import Join

import uuid

def home(request):
    try:
        join_id = request.session['join_id_ref']
        obj = Join.objects.get(id=join_id)
    except:
        obj = None
    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        new_join_old, created = Join.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            new_join_old.ref_id = get_ref_id()
            if not obj == None:
                new_join_old.friend = obj
            new_join_old.ip_address = get_ip(request)
            new_join_old.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_join_old .ref_id)
    context = {'form': form}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Don't concatenate your path component by doing `BASE_DIR + "\Templates"`, use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Templates")` instead. That beeing said, this may be your problem. Also report your full error message. Not just a part of it.

Comment: Oh, yes, that works, thank you!